# Draggable and droppable is not working in wordpress admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

In my wordpress metabox I am creating drag drop and sortable metabox field.

loaded jquery UI (full stable version) loaded in admin as.

```
function load_custom_wp_js() {

wp_register_script( 'jQuery_Ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.js');
wp_enqueue_style( 'jQuery_Ui' );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_js' );
```

relative CSS:

```
 ul#content-box{
     position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;padding:20px 0px;background:#C7C7C7;
    }

    ul#content-box li.field{
     float:left;width:20%;height:50px;border:2px solid #787878;border-radius:2px;margin:3px 19px;background:#909090
    }
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery( "ul#contnet-box" ).sortable({
            });
      });

</script>
```

above Sortable is working fine for me, but for following draggable function

```
jQuery( init );

function init() {
  $('ul#content-box').draggable();
}
```

throws error  `TypeError: jQuery(...).draggable is not a function` . same error for droppable too. sortable is working fine, but problem with draggable and droppable. can anyone help me about actual problem.is there any conflict in wordpress admin?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem while working on a plugin. I googled it hours long and finally created this solution:

Copy this code to your plugin's main php file (take care of the name of the function, which is in the add_action part too).

```
function add_custom_jquery_ui() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_jquery_ui' );
```

It enables the named handles from the denieds. Of course, you/others can name the other jQuery UI handles in the function from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress already includes [individual handles for many popular scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Handles_and_Their_Script_Paths_Registered_by_WordPress), including most of the jQuery UI functions. Unless you have a *really* good reason not to, you should be using the script files included with WP rather than your own.

My guess is that either Wordpress Core or another plugin is enqueuing `jquery-ui-sortable` before your call to enqueue the whole jQuery UI library, which is causing your call to fail. You should see an error about this in your browser's javascript console, and should see the code loaded by inspecting an admin page's source.

Try using only `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery-ui-draggable' );`

Comment: actual Mistake in enqueue. Instead of "wp_enqueue_script" I typed "wp_enqueue_style" .corrected it but now throwing another error "TypeError: $.widget.extend is not a function

Comment: Take a look at how you are calling the jQuery functions too. Wordpress' default is no-conflict mode, so you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. You're using `jQuery` when you call `sortable`, but you're using `$` when you call `draggable`.